# WCF Service with static variable and with two virtual directories

Tags: wcf, appdomain, static-variables, endpoint

I have a WCF service with two endpoints/virtual directories,

localhost/A/X.svc

localhost/B/X.svc

and it looks like, that both "endpoint" has an own instance from the static variable. I've already know that it is because of the AppDomain. But is it possible that both enpoints use the same AppDomain?

Comment: Very similar question was already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333557/iis7-wpas-multiple-wcf-services-in-same-appdomain

Comment: Yes, similar. But not the same. And there is no a really answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to share data between AppDomain, you could consider a different a approach than static variables which are effectively AppDomain bound. For instance files, a data base or [memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx) (to name but a few).

Comment: I don't want to share data between appdomains, but I want to run both under one AppDomain, if it's possible. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think, default, their endpoint are different, like "abc.com/A/X.svc" and "abc.com/B/X.svc"

Comment: I've just one endpoint definition, but in the IIS I have two virtual directories.

Comment: maybe you should set the endpoint address to decide only svc file.<endpoint address="/Address1"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                  contract="UE.Samples.IHello"/>